# Looking to upgrade my hosting for my web app from a cloud instance to Heroku & am using serve to deliver the build folder & nodemon on the server side

Tags: reactjs, express, deployment, command-line, command

I currently have my web app deployed on a remote instance in the cloud.
This was done initially so I could test PoC.
My site has a react front end client in a client folder and a node.js express server running in a server folder.

I currently have a cron job runs npm start entry on the server side that uses **serve** to serve the client build folder and runs nodemon on the server side.

server package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "cd ../client/build && serve -l 80",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
```

My question is, does Heroku offer custom deployment commands so an npm run build can run first on the client side, then run npm start on the server side to serve the site?

I tried to get this to work with netlify, but they don't seemingly support this type of setup.
Their support docs also recommend Heroku if the app is running an express server.